# magento : any idea why the page displays up to 12 items (4 x 3) instead of all?

Tags: php, magento

I hired someone to develop my website and he used Magento to do it last summer. I used to have only a few products on each page, so I asked him to remove "Show 12 per page" / "View as Grid vs List" / "Sort By POSITION", and he did.

As I don't have many products, I decided to put them all in one page, so I went through Magento's "Manage Products" to do this.

After that, when I tested my website, it only displays 12 products (4 items per row and 3 rows) and there is no "Next" button.

I tried to contact the person who created my webpage, but no avail. He just disappeared. So I am trying to find by myself how to display all products.

Can anyone help me on this?
Although I don't know web programming well, I have a programming background.
Thank in advance.

Comment: You should switch hints on to check .phtml for this and then look at .phtml if something hard coded there.

Answer (score 0):

A. To show All Products in a Magento Category by Default

first copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` to the `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` directory

```
<?php
$limit = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getLimitVarName());
if ($limit && isset($limits[$limit])) {
    if ($limit == $defaultLimit) {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
    } else {
        $this->_memorizeParam('limit_page', $limit);
    }   
} else {
    $limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();
}
?>
```

This else on the outer if statement needs to be changed to a string rather than a number. So for example:

```
<?php
...
} else {
    $limit = 'all';
}   
?>
```

B. To remove the toolbar

1. goto to your theme `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and and comment below line

> echo $this->getToolbarHtml()

2. using XML updates

   1. Create an empty template under app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/blank.phtml
   2. Set the empty template for the toolbar block:

In your local.xml for a specific category with the ID 10:

```
<CATEGORY_10>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>blank.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_10>
```

Or directly in the custom layout update text field in the admin:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>blank.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are don't know magento and there are few products on listing page i'm giving you you simple hint that non developer also can do that correct. Keep backup of all files any mistakes can break your product listing page.

1. Go to
   `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

   find `getToolbarHtml()` and comment or remove  this code `echo
   $this->getToolbarHtml()`(There is two same lines in one page).

   [image]
2. Set maximum product list on listing page from backend(I have set it
   10,000 products per one page).

   [image]
3. clear cache at last.
    [image]